# Create a admin page in wordpress without admin menus ("wordpress sidebars")

Tags: wp-admin, admin, admin-menu

I'm creating a new page in WordPress admin for a theme. In this new page will be a list of people registered (in a form), but with few details / information. So when a person clicks on something, I would like to open a "pop-up" (with all information) but not display this popup/page in the menus of the WordPress administration. Is there any way?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built in ThickBox to display the popup by Ajax:

```
//first add thickbox to your page
function add_thickbox(){
    if(is_admin() && (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == "my-plugin-file.php") { 
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('thickbox',null,array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_style('thickbox.css', '/'.WPINC.'/js/thickbox/thickbox.css', null, '1.0');
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_script','add_thickbox');


//then in your user list for each user you add the thickbox 
//popup on the onclick and pass the info needed (like user id) so eg:

?>
<!-- for each user add -->
 <a class="thickbox" onclick="javascript: show_user_info(user_id)">user name</a>
<!-- and then add this function once --> 
<script>
function show_user_info(user_id){
    var aj_url = 'admin-ajax.php?action=my_get_user_info&user_id=' + user_id;
    tb_show('userinfo',aj_url );
}
</script>

<?php 
//so all you have left is to create the ajax processing function :
add_action('wp_ajax_my_get_user_info', 'my_AJAX_processing_function');
function my_AJAX_processing_function(){
    //echo user info 
    //and remember to die;  
}
```

Comment: great solution! I will try this!
but do you have no idea a way to load a admin page in wordpress without menus?

Comment: You can load different views in the same page by adding get parameters

Answer (score 0):

I would think you could add a css class to the body of that new admin page using a wordpress filter, then use css to hide the unwanted items within the page.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466073/add-a-custom-class-name-to-wordpress-body-tag

Comment: it's a good alternative solution, but I still want to no "load" html code, etc. no proccess the menu, not just visual.

Comment: Yes... the above solution is definitely better.  I misunderstand you intentions on first glance.